# Update New Databases on Upgrading Tridion Sites 9.6

Tags: content-delivery, content-manager, upgrade, database

we are Upgrading CM & CD to Tridion Sites 9.6 from 9.1.

As per Upgradation Process,
**CM/Topology/translation**  - We are Providing New Database Names on the time of Exe installation process and values are stored on Respective config files.
**CD** - Updating New Database Names on CD_Storage and Deployer_config related Config files.

Apart from this Config files, we need to update New Databases in Any other place ? means CM Database name on CD related database tables or viceversa. Please confirm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed a fresh 9.6 on a new server with the default DB Example : Tridion_cm , Tridion_Topology and Tridion_Translation  and you wanted to change the config to point to the new DB name or the the upgraded DB in that case yes you need to following the instructions below to update the DB on the following configuration

Content Manager

Run the following to decrypt the database settings (please backup the Content  Manager Web.config ):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "database" "C:\Tridion\Config"
```

refer to [link](https://gateway.sdl.com/CommunityKnowledge?articleName=000012777)

Topology Manager

The database for Topology Manager is configured in %TRIDION_HOME%\TopologyManager\web\Web.config, but you will likely need to decrypt this file to see the settings.

Run the following to decrypt the database settings (please backup the Topology Manager Web.config first):

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "database" "C:\Tridion\TopologyManager\web"` refer to [link](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000008073)

Translation Manager

`C:\Tridion\Translation Manager>EncryptTranslationManagerConfiguration.exe /d Passwords decrypted: C:\Tridion\config\TranslationManager.xml`  refer to [link](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000013454)

As you mentioned you have to update the Micro Services Configuration to point to the new Broker DB and State Store DB for Deployer.

There no no Content Manager DB related configuration that will required to be changed on the CD Side.

Hope it helps !!